Is there a name for this Latin dance style in 3?
I have heard a particular style of Latin music a few times in the last few years, and I don't know what it's called, or how to find it to listen again. All I remember is the rough rhythm of the bass line, and even more roughly the percussion. It's definitely a dance style, and the way I hear it is in 3. I've heard the Colombian salsa band Las Guaracheras play a song in this style, and more recently I heard it playing on the radio at a local restaurant. The server called it "Peruvian cumbia", but when I search this on YouTube or Google, I can't seem to find any music of the same style. I attached an image of how I might notate the bass line, as well as a basic audio demo I threw together, based on what I remember. Does this resemble any Mexican or Peruvian music, or other Latino style?
https://voca.ro/17GcB9wflnJi


are you sure you haven't written it a quarter note off? As in the beat 3 is actually supposed to be beat 1?

yeah I definitely hear it one quarter note off, I'd assume others do as well. How can you possibly hear it this way?

If it's like tumbao, the bassist mostly rests or ties over beat 1, so this is not unusual

I think your interpretation is wrong. Just listen to it. It's definitely not thought of this way as you've written it by any of the musicians performing it nor any single person listening to it

You're simply trying to project this onto that format but it does not fit naturally. You are shoving this into the mould that is where tumbao bass isn't on one. But no, this bass DOES belong on one. Attach a real song performed in this fashion, else I simply can't believe what you've written here is right in the slightest. This is clearly offset by a quarter note, and the fact you don't accept that is only out of stubbornness. Naturality shows this is off by a quarter note.

@Snared if you can't answer what is it or what it might be, why are you so confident about the notation? Why would the OP remember the syncopation wrong?

Looked a few minutes at this YT described it peruvian cumbia as having a longer beat and then two short at the end (around 4:40 mark) https://youtu.be/jzPQ7f0cbHs maybe it is the two short at the end you are hearing ? I have no idea about this genre though.

You've written it wrongly. Think about it - there's a C and a G. It makes more sense for the G to be at the end of a bar, and the C to start the next.  Also could easily be in 6 rather than 3. IMO.

The only Latin dance I could find that was anything like was the Baile Folklorico. Have a listen to that.

You might be better off trying to find a good representative song and then get charts for it instead of trying to transcribe from memory where the result apparently doesn't fit into an obvious style.

If this bass line doesn't fit any style that you know of, consider simply saying you don't recognize it or just moving on.

@SamOlson There are very many styles in South America, so finding one might be tough. As far as I'm aware, cumbia uses duple/quadruple meter. Searching around I found vals peruano/vals criollo, but in the recordings I could find, the bass emphasized the downbeat.

There are a couple of latin styles in three that have broadly that rhythm, try the Venezuelan Pajarillo, a form of Joropa, or Argentine Chacarera. While I'm not ruiling out a mistake in the rhythmic notation I think those so ready to denounce it as wrong may be unfamiliar with the bredth of Latin bass line rhythms. In isolation it's understandably hard to keep centred on the 1, with the whole band other instruments are highlighting the downbeat, and the back-loaded bass becomes the swinging lilt that characterises the rhythm. try this for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abdPbQWCU7M

Peruvian cumbia is rhythmically like most other cumbias from Columbia, Mexico etc. that are in 4/4 time. In cumbia the bass usually plays short half notes but will also sometimes play only beats 3&4 where the 4th beat anticipates the harmony of the following bar.
What is closest to what you describe that I’m aware of is Peruvian waltz. This is a style in 3/4 that is driven by guitar and cajón, a wooden box played as a percussion instrument. Sometimes other instruments such as bass are added.
The bass in Peruvian waltz will typically play dotted half notes or half-quarter per bar, which is fairly standard for any waltz. However as the songs develop and they reach the chorus section there is a change in rhythm and the prevailing rhythm becomes this, an example I wrote with a 1-4-5-4 progression:

Note that the bass does not play downbeats and it also does not anticipate the harmony of the next bar on the final beat like it would in cumbia and salsa.
In the following song at 0:57 the bass plays dotted half notes then at 1:11 it goes into the pattern I wrote.



It is possible that this is different from what you are looking for but this is the closest thing I know of to what you are asking about,
